# Impossible to generate java client code from some wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, wsdl2java, wsdl2code

I'm trying with this specific URL:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlFile>https://web.rbsuat.com/ab/webservices/merchant-ws?wsdl</wsdlFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But got the exception during the plugin execution:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.axis2:axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin:1.7.9:wsdl2code (default-cli) on project test: Error parsing WSDL: Connection reset -> [Help 1]

The most likely is that it would be SSLv3 related issue for the newset java when the SSLv3 is disabled and I should enable it by removing the

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3
```

from `JRE_HOME/lib/security/java.security`, however, I did it and still face the same problem

Actually, the URL https://web.rbsuat.com/ab/webservices/merchant-ws?wsdl can be reached from the browser without any problem.

Comment: I don’t know much about Apache Axis, but the command `wsimport "https://web.rbsuat.com/ab/webservices/merchant-ws?wsdl"` works without issue in Java 8 and Java 10, so I doubt the SSL protocol is the problem.

Comment: it looked like the IDE didn't picked up my config changes in jre folder until it was restarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the IDE didn't picked up my config changes in jre folder until it was restarted, that was the reason. I had to restart my IDE

Answer (score 1):

1 - To generate Java client from a given WSDL file, you can use SoapUI tool to achieve that by following the instructions given in below links. It basically shows you how you can use different code generation tools like Axis 1.X, Axis 2, CXF 2.X, and .NET 2.0 to generate client code.

[SOAP Code Generation](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/soap-code-generation.html)

[Generating Client JAVA code for WSDL using SOAP UI](https://dzone.com/articles/generating-client-java-code)

2 - Once the Java client code is generated you can add the following parameter in your Java client before calling the external service to generate the SSL logs.

`System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");`

Then by seeing the SSL logs will come to know what is the problem you are facing when trying to call this service.

Comment: good idea for 1. but doesn't work for me; I'd like to make generation a part of development buildcycle, as the third-party wsdl can be changed from time to time. and that's why I need it more as a maven plugin than the external tool like soap ui

Comment: as for the 2. what is the best way to set up this property right to the whole maven execution to enabl;e this logging to the maven plugin?